# what index will be efficient for a query like : FieldA <= xxx AND FieldB >= xxx

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a database of **"range" of IP**. I want to store thoses IP in mongoDB. 
So I have documents like

```
{
  ...
  ipv4_start: int32,
  ipv4_end: int32,
  ...
}
```

Now, **What index I can create** to speed up at maximum this query :

```
Where ipv4_start <= xxx AND ipv4_end >= xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually [compound indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/) are suited for this.

> The order of the fields listed in a compound index is important

When you build an index like `{field1: 1, field2: 1}` then querying on `field2` will not utilize the index. hence if you're planning to use any of these field indexes for queries that do not require the second field you should put that field first when creating the index.

Another thing to consider if you usually query the "end" of the data you should build a descending index instead of a ascending one.

Comment: I don't think compound indexes will help me a lot here :( because compound are good if you do equality compare on the first field like field = xxx and field2 <= xxxx but that not what i need :(

Answer (score 0):

Just make them both an index.  your query example will use the indexes.